# How to setText for QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: qt, qt5, settext

Qt5's documentation doesn't mention that `QPlainTextEdit` has `setText(QString)` like `QTextEdit` does. But, I don't think it's impossible. The only way I found is to use `QTextDocument` which can has `setPlainText(const QString& text)`. So I have to do this:

```
plain_text_edit->setDocument(text_document);
```

The problem is `text_document` should be a pointer. Not like `QTextEdit`'s `setText` which can take a local variable as it's parameter. So, is there anyway to do `setText` like to `QPlainTextEdit`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's very simple, just [get the current document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#document) and [set its text](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#setPlainText):

```
plain_text_edit->document()->setPlainText(text);
```

---

Alternative way, just call [this method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#setPlainText):

```
plain_text_edit->setPlainText(text);
```

---

You could also use [text cursor of the editor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#textCursor) in many ways to achieve this, most simply by [selecting](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#selectAll) entire existing text (assuming the editor is not empty), then doing [`plain_text_edit->TextCursor().insertText(text);`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#insertText) (which replaces currently selected text with usual paste semantics), but for the simple case of replacing all text, that's overcomplicated.

Comment: plain_text_edit->setPlainText(text); also seems to work

Comment: @peter70 Interesting that I missed that, yet found `appendPlainText`... it doesn't seem to be a recent addition either.